# Ribbon animation code too repetitive

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I spent the last two days getting a ribbon animation to work with divs so that I can later add li link elements to them to act as a menu. I used the progess bar animation code as inspiration from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp). The animation works great, only issue is that the code is very un-DRY. I tried to simplify the code by not repeating myself in the CSS and especially not in the javascript but I kept getting closure issues even after using self invoked functions. I would be greatful if anyone can give me some advice or even a solution that will greatly shorten my code to have the same animation effect. I know that I will have several ribbons on the page, each with different number of ribbon layers, so the code as it is can get very complicated very fast. N.B the code below is the working version.

```js
function move1() {
  var width = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById("ribbon-part-1");
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}


function move2() {
  var width = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById("ribbon-part-2");
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1)

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 2;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function move3() {
  var width = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById("ribbon-part-3");
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1)

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 2;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function move4() {
  var width = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById("ribbon-part-4");
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1)

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 2;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function move5() {
  var width = 0;
  var elem = document.getElementById("end-ribbon");
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1)

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 2;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}

function move() {
  setTimeout(move1, 300);
  setTimeout(move2, 600);
  setTimeout(move3, 900);
  setTimeout(move4, 1200);
  setTimeout(move5, 1500);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.front-ribbon {
  position: relative;
  /*background-color: grey;*/
  height: 23px;
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: skewY(-11deg);
}

.back-ribbon {
  position: relative;
  /*background-color: grey;*/
  height: 23px;
  width: 160px;
  transform: skewY(4.7deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

#ribbon-part-1 {
  background-color: rgb(70, 125, 76);
  height: 23px;
  width: 0%;
}

#ribbon-part-2 {
  background-color: rgb(89, 166, 101);
  height: 23px;
  width: 0%;
}


/*Including the code below will allow for a reverse progressive bar*/
.front-ribbon #ribbon-part-2 {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

#ribbon-part-3 {
  background-color: rgb(70, 125, 76);
  height: 23px;
  width: 0%;
}

#ribbon-part-4 {
  background-color: rgb(89, 166, 101);
  height: 23px;
  width: 0%;
}


/*Including the code below will allow for a reverse progressive bar*/
.front-ribbon #ribbon-part-4 {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

#end-ribbon {
  fill: rgb(70, 125, 76);
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript ribbon animation</h1>

<div class="back-ribbon">
  <div id="ribbon-part-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="front-ribbon">
  <div id="ribbon-part-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="back-ribbon">
  <div id="ribbon-part-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="front-ribbon">
  <div id="ribbon-part-4"></div>
</div>

<svg id="end-ribbon">
  <path d="M-6 17 L35 24 L24 10 Z" />
</svg>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: If you don't have an explicit question and would like a code review on functional code, I believe you would have better luck over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps automate the creation of the different ribbons and their styles with DOM manipulation in the JS body, using ReactJS or similar.